# CircleCI branch filter is not working within "jobs > build" section

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

I'm brand new to CircleCI and below is my latest attempt at adding a branch filter. I don't need to use a workflow, so I'm following the documentation [found here](https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/115015953868-Filter-branches-for-jobs-and-workflows) which appears to tell you to put it under the `jobs > build` section. When this builds instead it blows up with the following message

ERROR IN CONFIG FILE:

[#/jobs/build] 0 subschemas matched instead of one

1. [#/jobs/build] only 1 subschema matches out of 2

|   1. [#/jobs/build] extraneous key [branches] is not permitted

|   |   Permitted keys:

|   |     - description

|   |     - parallelism

|   |     - macos

|   |     - resource_class

|   |     - docker

|   |     - steps

|   |     - working_directory

|   |     - machine

|   |     - environment

|   |     - executor

|   |     - shell

|   |     - parameters

|   |   Passed keys:

|   |     - executor

|   |     - branches

|   |     - steps

2. [#/jobs/build] expected type: String, found: Mapping

|   Job may be a string reference to another job

```
version: 2.1

orbs:
android: circleci/android@0.2.0 

jobs:
build:
  executor: android/android
  branches:
    only:
      - develop
  steps:
    - checkout
    - setup_remote_docker: 
        docker_layer_caching: true       
    - run:
        name: Increment build id
        command: sed "s/_buildNum/${CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM}/g" -i build.gradle
```

Comment: "branches" is a valid key within "filters" key that is available when used under workflows, not beneath jobs declaration.

Answer (score 0):

It's been long but someone might get some ideas.
You can filter by branches on workflow. Not on jobs.

Here goes an workflow example that is run only on my `dev` branch -

```
version: 2.1

orbs:
  python: circleci/python@1.5.0
  aws-cli: circleci/aws-cli@3.1.3

jobs:
  build: 
    #  will use a python 3.10.2 container
    docker:
      - image: cimg/python:3.10.2
    working_directory: ~/project

    steps:
      - checkout
    ........
    ........

# Invoke jobs via workflows
workflows:
  dev_workflow:
    # development branch workflow
    jobs:
      - build:
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                  - dev/cicd-integration
```

Happy coding!